# How to find USA Water Hardness shapefiles?

Tags: shapefile, data

I want to find USA water hardness shapefiles. I have searched for it from here: https://www.epa.gov/waterdata/waters-geospatial-data-downloads but without success.
Is there any good data source from where I can download these boundaries?

Comment: If you are seeking open data then you can always ask at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.